# Visual Studio 2013 reference version displayed vs runtime version used

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, gac

I am using two different versions of the same dll in two projects. They are both located in the GAC. Visual Studio properly resolves the two versions in the properties panel and "specific version" is set to true.

When running the application it crashes with a MethodNotFoundException and an AccessViolationException. I can see in the Debugger output that only the newer version is loaded and the old version is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 and .Net 4.5.1 may add the [AutoGenerateBindingRedirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx) property to projects. This may cause an incorrect binding at runtime. Simply remove the AutoGenerateBindingRedirects property from the .csproj file.